# PHP CSV Extract matching rows only running once and slow

Tags: php, csv

I am looping through a set of IDs and comparing them against a src CSV file, when it finds a matching ID it puts it into a new dest CSV file

**src CSV**

```
ids,value,color
1,value1 ,red
2,value2,oramge
3,value3,blue
4,value4,purple
5,value5,pink
6,value6,yellow
7,value7,green
8,value8,black
9,value9,white
```

**php**

```
$ids = array(
"7",
"9",
"3"
);


$srcFile = fopen("src.csv", "r");

$destFile = fopen("dest.csv","w");

foreach ($ids as $id) {

    while (($row = fgetcsv($srcFile, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {

        if ($row[0] == $id) {

            fputcsv($destFile, $row);

        }

    }

}

fclose($srcFile);
fclose($destFile);
```

The problem I am having is that it only runs once and appears to exit once it has found the first match. Plus, I am not sure how efficient this method is going to be if I hit it with a thousand records instead.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is your source CSV always going to be sorted?

Comment: The problem is that you're looping over disk-access functions (`fgetcsv` and `fputcsv`), which are magnitudes slower than memory-only operations.  Try putting your entire source file into an array and perform your search(es) on that array, putting your "found" values into a new array.  Then write that new array to disk at the end.  `$vals = array_map('str_getcsv', file('./src.csv'));`

Answer (score 1):

Use [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check that your csv row id is exist in array or not.

You should try below code-

**PHP**

```
<?php
$ids = array(
    "7",
    "9",
    "3"
);


$srcFile = fopen("src.csv", "r");

$destFile = fopen("dest.csv","w");

while (($row = fgetcsv($srcFile, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    echo $row[0];
    if (in_array($row[0], $ids)) {
        fputcsv($destFile, $row);
    }
}

fclose($srcFile);
fclose($destFile);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because you repeating your `while` loop for every ID in the array. Try to use your code like this and search for the ID using [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
<?php
$ids = array(
"7",
"9",
"3"
);


$srcFile = fopen("src.csv", "r");

$destFile = fopen("dest.csv","w");

while (($row = fgetcsv($srcFile, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
if (in_array($row[0], $ids)) {
    fputcsv($destFile, $row);
}
}

fclose($srcFile);
fclose($destFile);
?>
```